# grep command and [ ]

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I'm learning bash code and today I'm studying   the command `grep`.

if I run

`$ ps -fU user | grep thunderbird`

terminal shows:

```
user  17410     1  0 10:09 ?        00:00:20 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
user  18990 15896  0 12:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto thunderbird
```

But if I run:

```
$ ps -fU user | grep [t]hunderbird
```

terminal shows:

```
user  17410     1  0 10:09 ?        00:00:20 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
```

why? I read the guide but I don't understand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, when you run `ps | grep ...`, the `grep` process is also shown in the output of `ps`. The default `ps` output includes the arguments a process was launched with, not only the process's name. This means that if you run `grep foo`, and there is a running process called `foo`, there will be two `ps` results matching `foo`: the `foo` process and the `grep` itself since it is searching for `foo`. This is why you get two lines when running `ps -f | grep thunderbird`.

Now, the `[ ]` is a regular expression construct which defines a list of characters, a character class. For example, `[abc]` will match `a` or `b` or `c`. When you run `ps -f | grep [t]hunderbird`, that class only contains a single character so is equivalent to `thunderbird` without the brackets. However, the `grep` process was launched with `[t]hunderbird` as an argument this time, and not `thunderbird`. Therefore, its line in the output of `ps` will contain `[t]hunderbird`. It will look like this:

```
terdon   23101 10991  0 16:53 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color [t]hunderbird
```

This means that it is not matched when you run `ps -f | grep thunderbird` since it contains `[t]hunderbird` and not `thunderbird`.

This is a common trick to avoid matching the `grep` process itself when running `ps | grep`. Another alternative is to run `ps -f | grep foo | grep -v grep` to exclude the `grep`. The best approach, however, is to use a program specifically designed for this, `pgrep`:

```
$ pgrep -l thunderbird
11330 thunderbird
```

Comment: terdon, as @Serg has removed his answer I am putting it here.... timing is related to when the process will appear in the process table and hence in the output....I read this from an answer of Gilles on U&L and later experimented it myself..I am on my phone so could not show it right now..

Comment: @heemayl timing might affect whether or not the `grep` process is launched before or after the `ps` one so whether it will be present in the output of `ps`. It has nothing to do with the issue here which is that the _string_ `[t]hunderbird` does not match the regex `[t]hunderbird`.

Comment: that's what I am trying to tell :).. if `ps` does not have the pipeline's `grep`, it will never be on the output..

Comment: @heemayl yes, I know, but that's not why the `[t]hunderbird` is not matching the `grep` process. `ps =f | grep [t]hunderbird` will _never_ match the `grep` process since the regex doesn't match it. Timing is irrelevant, it won't match it even if it is there.

Comment: aye guru..but my point is if the `grep` itself does not appear in the `ps` by then, no need for `[]`.. only `grep thunderbird` would suffice..no?

Comment: @heemayl yes, but I have never seen that happen. If you read in in one of Gilles's answers, I'm sure it does, but I have never seen it in the wild. Perhaps Gilles was talking about an embedded system or another flavor of *nix. I'm pretty sure that you'll never see this in a Linux box.

Comment: @heemayl I think you are referring to [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37597/22222) which states that the commands are run at the same time. Yes, one might start before the other but they run concurrently. If so, I don't know if it's even possible to have `ps` get the list of running processes before `grep` is launched. I very much doubt it.

Comment: sorry not that one..I know the processes start concurrently but it was about how fast `ps` can parse the process table & have something that started concurrently....

Comment: anyway I am gonna edit my answer & put this as a highly unlikely case as you have rightly pointed out..

Comment: @heemayl OK, I tested this and in 10000 tests, I got one case where the `grep` wasn't in the output of `ps`. So yes, it does happen but very, very rarely. As I said though, this is irrelevant here, the difference is in what `grep` is searching for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I know how ' |' means. I read all answers. I think that I have understood. In the second case the process is [t]hunderbird, so  grep find only the process 'thunderbird'. It is true?

Comment: Yeah..that's fairly conclusive..I have edited my answer already :)

Comment: @linofex sort of. In the second case, the _grep_ process is `grep [t]hunderbird` so the grep doesn't match it. Try running `grep [t]hunderbird` (just like that, no arguments, hit enter and it will stay there doing nothing). Then, open another terminal and run `ps -af | grep grep`.

Comment: `ps -f | grep foo | grtep -v grep` should be `ps -f | grep foo | grep -v grep`. I only found 3 characters to change in the entire answer and it won't allow an edit with less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case you're looking for any process with the word thunderbird in. There are two thunderbird and the grep command itself.

In the second you're also looking for `t` character followed by `hunderbird`, as the [t] means match any listed characters in the square bracket of which there's just the one, the letter t, but this time your two processes are

```
user  17410     1  0 10:09 ?        00:00:20 /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
user  18990 15896  0 12:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto [t]hunderbird
```

The second process does not match because the rexep [t]hunderbird does not match the **literal string** `[t]hunderbird` as the ] prevents the match.

Comment: Just a **TL;DR** for the lazy readers: treat output of second `ps` as text, and realize that second grep matches `t` and `hunderbird` , not `[`, `t`,`]`,  and `hunderbird , which is what second process looks like as string

Comment: @Serg perhaps you should check the comments below terdon's answer, regarding the timing issue..

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, whether `grep --color=auto thunderbird` will appear on the process table and hence on the output of `ps` depends on the time i.e. how busy is your system & how much time it takes for `ps` to show something on it's output (by parsing the process table)  that has started concurrently, `grep` in this case. Although this is a highly unlikely case and we can assume that that `grep` will appear on the output of `ps`.

Now, `[]` is a grep syntax which means (if not followed by other tokens) match any of the characters inside `[]`. So when you use `grep '[t]hunderbird'`, `grep` treats the `[t]` to match only `t`, as a result it would not appear in the output.

While using `grep thunderbird`, if it makes it way in the process table, we would find the `grep` process in the output as we are `grep`-ping for the same thing i.e. `grep thunderbird`.

Also note that `grep` is an alias to `grep --color=auto` causing it to appear in the output too.

Answer (score 1):

The [] in `grep` is used for character matching. If we take 
    `grep [tb]all my_file.txt`

It is equivalent to

```
grep tall my_file.txt
grep ball my_file.txt
```

It will execute `grep` with taking t+all and then it will execute `grep` by taking b+all.

For example: If we want to look for a word ABC or BBC in a file we can use the following grep command:

```
grep [AB]BC file_name
```

Here the [] will make `grep` to expand the the word by taking A, then it will expand the word by using B, thus creating ABC and BBC.